# Printf with gas assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, printf, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I don't know why I cannot print anything with `printf` in GAS assembly if `\n`(LF - newline) is missing at the end of the string. If I put the newline char `\n` the line prints, but if I remove `\n` the line doesn't print. Can someone tell me why?

```
.extern printf
.section .data

hello:
    .string "Hello!" # doesn't print this way when \n is missing

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
    nop
    movl $hello, %edi
    movl $0, %eax
    call printf

_end:    
    movq $60, %rax  #use the _exit syscall
    movq $0, %rdi   #return error code 0
    syscall         #make syscall
```

Comment: If you wish to use the C library (that `printf` is a part of), use `main` as entry point and do not use the `exit` syscall. You are not letting the C library shut down properly so the buffered line is not printed. PS: next time if you see your question comes out with broken formatting please fix it yourself. Use the preview as appropriate.

Comment: Try `.asciz` instead of `.string` in the definition of the string to output.

Comment: Sorry Jester for not meeting you high standards.

Comment: It's a pretty low standard to use proper formatting. You did see it [came out as a horrible mess](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37446595/1), right? And poor _zx485_ had to fix it for you. You are asking for help, it's basic courtesy to post properly.

Comment: Jester is correct, you should consider using `main` as an entry point and link against the _C_ runtime. You could then use `ret` to return to the _C_ runtime that called main (rather than `exit` syscall) which would properly flush the output buffers, and exit the program. If you are adamant on using `_start` as an entry point then rather than using the `exit` syscall you should call the `exit` function (via `call exit`). Put the return code into `%edi`.

Comment: Those aren't Jester's high standards, those are the standards for interfacing assembly and C.

Answer (score -2):

```
pushl %ebp
lea   hello, %edi
movl  %esp, %ebp /*<----*/
call  printf
popl  %ebp
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.